# Don't want the code but confirm if I can do an update based on a multi-column SELECT

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, custom-object

I know SQL very well, SOQL very little so bear with me while I ask a question above my current skillset.  I built a simple working model with several custom objects (standard objects didn't fit my needs for several reasons).  Rather than learn everything about Apex and SF, I am trying to learn what I need to when I need to--it sinks in easier and stays there.  On the flip side, I'm asking what may be an easy question so please be kind.

I created four custom tables--Service, Location, Vendor, and Cost.  The first three are quasi-picklists with the last having lookup fields and then a cost.  The intention is to say "a haircut in Arizona by John costs $10" or "a haircut in Arizona by Stacy costs $15".  This gives me the flexibility to pick a service--by location--offered by a vendor--and know the cost.

```
Cost:
    Service         Location         Vendor       Cost
    haircut         Tempe, AZ        John         $10
    haircut         Tempe, AZ        Stacy        $15
    shave           Tempe, AZ        John         .25
    haircut         Dallas, TX       Brian        $20
```

I have yet another object that schedules requests for these combinations.  It has a cost field but I'd like to automate it with a trigger (because a lookup is manual and only gets me the "name" of the cost).

I've found numerous examples of bad and bulkified triggers but can't find if it's possible.  Can I update a field with a value?  Yes.  Can I update it with a value chosen from a lookup table?  I don't know.

Any feedback is appreciated.  If it's badly designed or not possible, please let me know.

Thanks.

Mike

Comment: Echoing T.Rossi's last comment, the "native" approach is to use picklists and that makes other functionality in the platform simpler to use, allowing you and your customer to get more value from the platform. (And you can Google for opinions about normalization in Salesforce that sometimes recommend not taking ideas wholesale from SQL database.) You have reasons to not use picklists?

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd do it is to first create Maps of the "picklist" objects, so that I know, given a picklist name (e.g. haircut) what is the id of the record in that table. This approach uses 4 selects and 1 update, 1 select for every table, the first 3 to build maps, the last one to retrieve all the cost entries you need to modify. Bulding maps in memory is ok to limit the number of queries (governor limit 1) but makes you use more memory (governor limit 2..), so you may want to be sure your problem is feasible. There are special syntax for querying in for loops (for Account a : [SELECT...] // for List aList : [SELECT.. ]) which you should look depending on how many records you expect to cycle into.

I'm not sure I grasp the request, but the format looks out of what soql does. With nested queries in SOQL you can get at most things like "all the childs of a parent for every parent". You can give a look at this examples http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm
e.g. given a location entry of your model, you could get in a select all the cost obejcts that are linked to it.

Is there a reason why you didn't use a single object, "item", which has 3 picklist fields and one currency field? Picklists fields in salesforce are something like ENUM() but they can be handled via graphic user interface quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I went with separate objects partly because of normalization (my DB2/modeling background) but also because I want/need more fields than just the one.  For example, in Vendor, I'd want the address/phone/etc so I could reach them or send them payment.  And, yes, Contact has the fields I need.  I can't defend all the decisions I've made.  :)

Comment: As much as I love coding in Apex (not!), I think I'm going to hit the Pause button and rethink what I'm doing.  I'm approaching SF from a DB2/Access background and apparently doing my darndest to avoid using anything pre-built.  If I continue, I may paint myself into a corner so I will take a day, explore Accounts/Contacts and maybe Price, and see if I can use them somehow.  Thanks again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

To make this easy to query, you might want to consider making a key field on your Cost object. I'd also make the key field be unique (case-sensitive) so you don't have two costs for the same service, location and vendor. You could then have a workflow rule that updates the field with a concatenation of the three IDs.

In your trigger on the schedule, first build a list of strings of IDs based on all the schedules and then query it once.

Comment: I actually did make a formula field that concatenated the three "key" fields but, when I do a lookup, I couldn't seem to retrieve a different field.  I could limit the records displayed (using the filters available when creating/editing the custom field) but, still, all SF gave me was Name (the first field of the custom object).  It just seems so logically simple to me that I must be overlooking something obvious.  Or maybe I just have blinders on.  Sigh.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use lookup filters? That could work to pull in a reference to the costs. You'd then use a cross object formula to get the price. My original answer was about a trigger to bring the price into another field.

Comment: If I don't go back to a pre-fabbed object, I will be using a trigger (once I learn how).  Having a lookup field is fine but, if I then have to use a cross-object formula to get the field/data I want, I've got 2-3 fields with pointless data. If that's my choice, I'll leave Cost alone until I can do it properly without cluttering up my custom objects with temporary fields.  Thanks for the guidance.